# MemoryRouter and jest test

Tags: react-router, jestjs

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing

The react-router testing documentation is bit obscure to me.

How to write a test to check a  route is rendered

A Component. - *APage.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export default class APage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        A Page
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Writing a unit test to check , as per documentation.

*routes.test.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from "react-dom";
import APage from './APage'
import {MemoryRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

  test("render route", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/apage"]}>
        <APage />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });
```

It gives an error, 
Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
for render.

How do I write a basic test, like to test a component is rendered on a route.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Ok. Route testing has to be done by enzyme. not just using jest.

Followed https://medium.com/@antonybudianto/react-router-testing-with-jest-and-enzyme-17294fefd303

Used enzyme mount to test.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to comment on Remi's solution, since the API in React Router v6 is a little different (and the link to the docs leads now to a 404):

```js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
        
test("render route", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  render(
    <Router 
        location={history.location} // history.location has a default value of '/' 
        navigator={history}
    >
      <APage />
    </Router>
  );
})
```

[see github repo here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blame/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L290)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Router instead. Since that uses BrowserRouter. (see alternatives section on [react router example page](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing))

```js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

test("render route", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  history.push('/apage');
  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <APage />
    </Router>
  );
});
```

It could be that you should also add your page in a [Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route), but I'm not sure.

Then it would be something like:

```js
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

test("render route", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  history.push('/apage');
  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/aroute' render={(props) => (<APage {...props} />)} />
    </Router>
  );
});
```