# How to spy on `history` using `BrowserRouter` or `MemoryRouter`?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
react-router-dom@^5.1.0:
  version "5.1.2"

react@^16.12.0:
  version "16.12.0"

"@testing-library/react@^11.1.2":
  version "11.1.2"

history@^5.0.0:
  version "5.0.0"
```

Simplest example:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {render, act} from '@testing-library/react';
import {Router, useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';

test('Sample', async () => {
  const Component = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        history.push('/abc');
      }, 100);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, []);
    console.log(history.location, location);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{history.location.search}</div>
        <div>{location.search}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const history = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: [
      {
        pathname: '/',
        search: '',
      },
    ],
  });
  const pushFn = jest.spyOn(history, 'push');
  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Component />
    </Router>
  );
  expect(pushFn.mock.calls.length).toEqual(0);
  await act(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 125)));
  expect(pushFn.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  expect(pushFn.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(['/abc']);
});
```

---

That `console.log` line, before `history.push` call, it prints out:

```
    { pathname: '/',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: 'f2blf5di' } { pathname: '/',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: 'f2blf5di' }
```

Ok, as expected.

Now, after `history.push` call, it becomes:

```
    { pathname: '/abc',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: 'tz0v0qgf' } { action: 'PUSH',
      location:
       { pathname: '/abc',
         search: '',
         hash: '',
         state: null,
         key: 'tz0v0qgf' } }
```

So...that `location` object changes completely, but `history.location` still has the same object structure.

Using `MemoryRouter` or `BrowserRouter` fixes this, but I still need to spy on the `history.push` call as to make sure that there is only X number of pushes happened.

I need to do this check because some bugs might happen due to some `useEffect` in a component where it gets run multiple times and doing multiple `history.push` with the exact same parameters. Causing users having to hit browser back button (X + 1) times to get back to where they were.

---

Tried this as well, but `history.goBack()` doesn't change the location at all.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {render, act, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import {BrowserRouter, useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import window from 'global/window';

test('Sample', async () => {
  const Component = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        history.push('/abc?foo=fooValue');
        history.push('/abc?foo=fooValue');
        history.push('/abc?foo=fooValue');
      }, 100);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, []);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{history.location.search}</div>
        <div>{location.search}</div>
        {__DEV__ && <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>back</button>}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Component />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/');
  expect(window.location.search).toEqual('');
  await act(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200)));
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/abc');
  expect(window.location.search).toEqual('?foo=fooValue');
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'back'}));
  expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/');
  expect(window.location.search).toEqual('');
});
```

---

**How do I use `MemoryRouter` or `BrowserRouter` and spy on the `history.push` call?
Or maybe, how do I make `Router` to not change the `location` from `useLocation` object structure after `history.push`?**

---

[UPDATE] 15 DEC 2020 13:00

After spending 2 days on this, I will just settle with this solution:

```
const memoryRouterRef: {current: any} = React.createRef<any>();
render(
  <MemoryRouter ref={memoryRouterRef}>
  ...
  </MemoryRouter>
);
...do some stuff...
expect(memoryRouterRef.current.history.location.pathname).toEqual(...);
expect(memoryRouterRef.current.history.location.search).toEqual(...);
expect(memoryRouterRef.current.history.length).toEqual(...);

memoryRouterRef.current.history.goBack(); // This works now!!

// We can now check the pathname / search to make sure user can use the browser back button properly
expect(memoryRouterRef.current.history.location.pathname).toEqual(...);
expect(memoryRouterRef.current.history.location.search).toEqual(...);
```

At the end of the day, I don't think this is a job for unit tests. It should just be e2e tests. For now though, this is enough for me.

---

Update Apr 11, 2022:

You can make it cleaner by doing this instead:

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    render(
      <Router history={history}>
        ...
      </Router>
    );
```

Everything else is the same. You can still do `expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(...)`.

Some differences are instead of `history.goBack()`, you do `history.back()`. Just look at the `history` package documentation on what is available.
The other one would be `history.length`. There is no `length` property. You should just check for the index instead, `history.index`.

Answer (score 0):

Update October 27, 2023. Using React Router V6

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
        
test("render route", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  render(
    <Router 
        location={history.location} // history.location has a default value of '/' 
        navigator={history}
    >
      <APage />
    </Router>
  );
})

// Everything else is (still) the same. You can do now:

expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(...).
```

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736854/memoryrouter-and-jest-test)

Thanks to [raaaahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8137604/raaaahman) for saving me a few hours on this.